f continuous a.e implies f measurable
let $f:\mathbb {R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ a function that is  continuous a.e., then $f$ is measurable
I know the solution of this problem, but I tried a different approach
:If I call $C$ the set of points of continuity
$D$ the set of points of discontinuity,
then if $A$ is an open set $f^{-1}(A)=(f^{-1}(A)\cap C)\cup(f^{-1}(A)\cap D)$
the last set is measurable because a subset of a null set , but lebeasue measure is complete
at the beginning I thought $f^{-1}(A)\cap C=(f_{\vert C})^{-1}(A)$ so I started wirting things   but I am not so sure about that ... can you please give me a counterexample if it is not right ?
MY FULL SOLUTION
$f_{\vert C})^{-1}(A)=f^{-1}(A)\cap C$ by definition
f is continuous a e on $C$ if and only if $f_{\vert C})$ is continuous i e  $f_{\vert C})^{-1}(A) $ is open in $C$
open set of $C$ are made of $V\cap C$ where $V$ is open in $\mathbb R^n$
now  $f^{-1}(A)=(f^{-1}(A)\cap C)\cup(f^{-1}(A)\cap D)$
the right part is measurable
and the left part too because is $V\cap E$ where V is open

It is true, and easily proved, so you get $f_{|C}^{-1}(A)$ is open as a subset of $C,$ but not necessarily an open subset of $\mathbb R^n.$ it is not clear where you go from there.

@ThomasAndrews     thanks for your help I wanted to say  that $f^{-1}$ is continuous on $C$ so the pre immage of open set is open... where is the error ?

$f_{|C}$ is a continuous function on $C,$ not $\mathbb R^n,$ so its pre image is open only as a subset of $C.$ An open subset of $C$ is not  necessarily an open subset of $\mathbb R^n.$ I can construct a function which is continuous at every irrational number, discontinuous at the rationals. Then your pre-image is a subset of the irrationals, and hence cannot be open as a subset of $\mathbb R.$

@ThomasAndrews is that right now ?
